# Interpretation of some general examples on Operads

Tags: category-theory

Fix some countable set $X=\{x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\}$ of variables. Hencefore we denote by$ (x_{1},\dots,x_{n})$  the nonassociative word that is obtained from $X$ by some bracketing. Denote by Alg(n) the linear span of all nonassociative words of the form $(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})$ . I am confused of the following  natural composition rule 
$Comp(u,v_{1},\dots,v_{n})=u(v_{1}(x_{(1,1)}^\pi,\dots,x_{(1,m_{1})}^{\pi}),\dots,)$
Where $\pi=(m_{1},\dots,m_{n})$ is in the set of n-partitions of $m$.
May you please help me to construct a simple example?

A note on partitions:
Fix two integers $m  \geq n\geq 1$ . An ordered tuple $\pi=(m_{1},\dots, m_{n})$ of integers $m_{i} \geq 1$ is called an n-partition of $m$ if $m_{1}+\dots+m_{n}=m$ . In fact, $\pi$ is in the set of these partitions.

Comment: Isn't this just "substitute $x_i$ by $v_i$ in $u$"?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, but what of the partition $\pi$?

Comment: @LordsharktheUnknown I think so; but I am thinking to how apply it for a small example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, $Comp(u,v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is just what you get by substituting $v_1,\dots,v_n$ for each of the variables in $u$.  For instance, suppose we have: $$u=(x_1x_2)x_3$$ $$v_1=x_1x_2$$ $$v_2=x_1(x_2(x_3x_4))$$ $$v_3=x_1.$$

Then the partition is $\pi=(2,4,1)$ (the numbers being the arities of the $v_i$) and
$$Comp(u,v_1,v_2,v_3)=(
\underbrace{(x^\pi_{(1,1)}x^\pi_{(1,2)})}_{v_1(x^\pi_{(1,1)},x^\pi_{(1,2)})}
\underbrace{(x^\pi_{(2,1)}(x^\pi_{(2,2)}(x^\pi_{(2,3)}x^\pi_{(2,4)})))}_{v_2(x^\pi_{(2,1)},\dots,x^\pi_{(2,4)})}
)
\underbrace{x^\pi_{(3,1)}}_{v_3(x^\pi_{(3,1)})}
= ((x_1x_2)(x_3(x_4(x_5x_6))))x_7.$$

(Here I assume the notation $x^\pi_{(j,k)}$ refers to $x_{m_1+\dots+m_{j-1}+k}$ as that is the only definition that makes sense in context.)